# django 1.5 custom user - separate application in admin

Tags: django, model, django-custom-user

I've created a custom user model as described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

**models.py**

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_partner  = models.BooleanField(_('partner status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user is partner or employee'))
```

**forms.py**

```
class AccountChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account

class AccountCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

**admin.py**

```
class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = AccountChangeForm
    add_form = AccountCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_partner', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

admin.site.register(Account, AccountAdmin)
```

all works fine, but now Users and Groups are in different applications in admin:
[image: separate applications]

Is it possible to put custom user model and Groups in one application?

Comment: I've the same problem with Django 1.8 :(